# Detecting mismatch where there are multiple occurences of array elements in more than one array

Tags: javascript

I have the following arrays:

```
const primary =
[
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
];

const secondary = [
 {recordId:123, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
];
```

So I want to display a list of recordIds where we don't have an equal number of records in either array for given recordId.

e.g In above example `recordId:123` has 3 x records in primary array but only 2 x in the secondary array, therefore because the number of records don't match up for this Id
I want to be able to report on this recordId.

I've had a go and this is what solution I've produced so far using vanilla Javascript:

```
const missingRecords = []

const primaryOccurences = primary.reduce((acc, val) 
 => acc.set(val.recordId, 1 +   (acc.get(val.recordId) || 0)), new Map());
const secondaryOccurences = secondary.reduce((acc, val) 
 => acc.set(val.recordId, 1 + (acc.get(val.recordId) || 0)), new Map());

console.log(primaryOccurences);
console.log(secondaryOccurences);

primaryOccurences.forEach((value,key)=> {
for (const[skey, svalue] of secondaryOccurences.entries()) {
 if(skey === key && value !== svalue) {
   missingRecords.push(key);
  }
 }
})

console.log(missingRecords);
```

```js
const primary = [{
    recordId: 123,
    type: "Primary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 123,
    type: "Primary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 123,
    type: "Primary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 9393,
    type: "Primary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 9393,
    type: "Primary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 9393,
    type: "Primary"
  },
];

const secondary = [{
    recordId: 123,
    type: "Secondary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 123,
    type: "Secondary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 9393,
    type: "Secondary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 9393,
    type: "Secondary"
  },
  {
    recordId: 9393,
    type: "Secondary"
  },
];


const missingRecords = []

const primaryOccurences = primary.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val.recordId, 1 + (acc.get(val.recordId) || 0)), new Map());
const secondaryOccurences = secondary.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val.recordId, 1 + (acc.get(val.recordId) || 0)), new Map());

console.log(primaryOccurences);
console.log(secondaryOccurences);

primaryOccurences.forEach((value, key) => {
  for (const [skey, svalue] of secondaryOccurences.entries()) {
    if (skey === key && value !== svalue) {
      missingRecords.push(key);
    }
  }
})

console.log(missingRecords);
```

Running this code produces the following:

```
[123]
```

So is there a better alternative to the above from a performance standpoint? I'm open to other ideas / suggestions.

Comment: what do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Performance wise. I will update the above.

Comment: Is there a scenario where a `recordId` may exist in `primary` but not in `secondary`? Or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one map. Will be better for big arrays.
It require only one loop. And you can detect if there are more records in the `primary` ( `> 0`) or in the `secondary` ( `< 0`)

Also you can rewrite `reduce` in `for` notation but it make sense only for large arrays

https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/19290/0/so-two-map-compare

```js
const primary =
[
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
];

const secondary = [
 {recordId:123, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
];

const missingRecords = []

const occurences = primary.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val.recordId, 1 + (acc.get(val.recordId) || 0)), new Map());
secondary.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val.recordId, (acc.get(val.recordId) || 0) - 1), occurences);

for (const [skey, svalue] of occurences.entries()) {
    if (svalue !== 0) {
        missingRecords.push(skey);
    }
}

console.log(missingRecords);
```

Comment: Is the -1 required so it allows us detect that there is mismatch i.e there isn't equal number in primary and secondary arrays.

Comment: Yes. We count sum of occurrence record with specific id in primary array and then subtract sum of records in second array. Thats why if zero count in records  are same in both arrays. If more than zero - there are more occurrence in first array, if less than zero more in second array

Answer (score 0):

if you use `Map()` why don't you use its methods to check but use `Object.entries()` !?

I add both cases that exist only in A and only in B :

```js
const primary =
[
 {recordId:122, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Primary" },
]

const secondary = [
 {recordId:123, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:123, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9393, type: "Secondary" },
 {recordId:9394, type: "Secondary" },
]
const primaryOccurences = primary.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val.recordId, 1 + (acc.get(val.recordId) || 0)), new Map())
const secondaryOccurences = secondary.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val.recordId, 1 + (acc.get(val.recordId) || 0)), new Map())
const resultPrimary = []
const resultSecondary = []
primaryOccurences.forEach((count, id) => {
  if (primaryOccurences.get(id) !== secondaryOccurences.get(id)) {
    resultPrimary.push(id)
  }
    secondaryOccurences.delete(id)
})
secondaryOccurences.forEach((v, id) => resultSecondary.push(id))
const mergeResult = resultPrimary.concat(resultSecondary)
console.log(resultPrimary, resultSecondary, mergeResult)
```